# In BASH I need to change some environment variables based on output of a perl script. In tcsh I can use an alias eval combo. Can't in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I need to change some environment variables based on output of a perl script with parameters. 
In tcsh I can use an alias command that evals the output of the perl script.

tcsh:

```
alias setsdk 'eval `/localhome/guyc/bin/setsdk.pl tcsh \!*`'
```

then I use:

```
$ setsdk 20.0.0.22
```

And it works.

bash: I've tried many permutation of escaping the parameters but none work.

```
alias setsdk='eval `/localhome/guyc/bin/setsdk.pl bash $1`'
alias setsdk='eval `/localhome/guyc/bin/setsdk.pl bash \$1`'
```

Please help!

Answer (score 2):

Use a function instead; `bash` aliases don't take parameters:

```
setsdk () {
  eval "$(/localhome/guyc/bin/setsdk.pl bash "$1")"
}
```